# Trying to pick the array based on component's prop, create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get a prop in my ProductPanel component to represent the array name? 
`<ProductSquare PanelId = {"door"}/>` I would like `door` to match the array named `door`

Or if that doesn't make sense... `if( this.prop.PanelId === arrayName ) {
than map through the array and display all the products }`

This logic would make sense because I have multiple tables (door,lighting,chair,window)

```js
//ProductInformation.js

export const door = [
  {
    id: 1,
    productSquareId: 'door',
    productImage: require('./door.png'),
    companyImage: require('./logo.png'),
    price: '$55.99',

  },
  {
    id: 2,
    productSquareId: 'door',
    productImage: require('./door.png'),
    companyImage: require('./logo.png'),
    price: '$55.99',

  },
  ]
  
  export const lighting = [
  {
    id: 1,
    productSquareId: 'lighting',
    productImage: require('./lighting.png'),
    companyImage: require('./logo.png'),
    price: '$55.99',

  }
]
```

```js
//a Method inside my ProductPanel.js  which renders maps the arrays and returns Product Panels 


PopulateProductSquares(PanelId)
{
  const ProductSquares = door.map((door, i) =>
    <div className = "ProductSquare">
    <img  className = "MainImage" src ={door[i].productImage}  alt = "test"/>
    <img  className = "CompanyImage" src ={door[i].companyImage} alt = "test"/>

      <button className = "AddButton">
        Add
      </button>

      <button className = "InfoButton">
        Info
      </button>

    </div>
  )

  return (
     ProductSquares
  )
}

  render() {
    return (

          this.PopulateProductSquares(this.props.PanelId)
    )

}
```

```js
// lastly a snippet inside my main component where I put in various panels of different products

<ProductSquare PanelId = {"door"}/>
```

Comment: Why not just `<ProductSquare panelId = {door} />` ?!

Comment: Oh did not know I can call it a variable as well. I was wondering though what if I inputted lighting instead of door. What can I do so all the "variables of `door`" changes to lighting without me hard coding.